# How to send table info into a form? Spring Solved

Tags: spring-mvc

For a long time I have been looking for a way to send the table info I click to the form so I can submit it well I finally did it and will have the code below in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to send info from a clicked table to the form for submiting.

But make sure that you have your table named you are working with. Also if your row is off then where it says ("myTable").rows[row]. Change it to ("myTable").rows[row+x] or ("myTable").rows[row-x] x being how much it is off if any. Also repeat text = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[row].cells[1].innerHTML;
        $("input").eq(1).val(text); every time you have something in the table to submit to the form updateing the numbers with the coresponding index

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "tr" ).click(function() {
        var row = $(this).index();
        var text = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[row].cells[0].innerHTML;
        $("input").eq(0).val(text);
        text = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[row].cells[1].innerHTML;
        $("input").eq(1).val(text);
    });
});
```